# Run Macro in Word when picture is added/removed from Picture Content control

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using the following macro to resize an image once added via the Picture Content Control feature in word as a solution to the default resizing that occurs once a image is removed from the Picture Content Control (the size isn't preserved and the image box reverts to a larger size).

This macro resizes, but I'm looking to see how i can automatically run the macro every time an image is added or removed from the Picture Content Control box?

```
Sub ResizePhotos()
Dim pic As InlineShape

For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With pic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        If .Width > .Height Then
            .Height = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        Else
            .Width = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        End If
         .Range.Paragraphs(1).Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: There isn’t an event that fires either when a picture is added or deleted. The closest you can get would probably be something like `ContentControlOnExit`.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt thanks for the feedback - are you able to provide any guidance on writing the code to support this? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not start by looking up [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.contentcontrolonexit)?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a content control on-exit macro. For example:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With CCtrl
  If .Type = wdContentControlPicture Then
    With .Range.InlineShapes(1)
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    End With
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With CCtrl
  If .Type = wdContentControlPicture Then
    With .Range.InlineShapes(1)
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    End With
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```